# How can I count same value from two column same time?

Tags: java, count

Currently I am able to get a result for "yes" from "book" column, however I cannot get result count for "yes" from "book" and "shelf" from the same row.

**Code:**

```
string query = "SELECT book,shelf FROM table";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
int bCount = 0;

while (rs.next()) 
{
    string crs = rsx.getString("book");
    if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(crs)) 
        bCount++;

}
```

Yet the above code is not working.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
int mixCount = 0;

while (rs.next()) 
{
    string crs = rsx.getString("book");
    string cty = rsx.getString("shelf");

    if (equalsIgnoreCase(crs).equalsIgnoreCase(cty))
        mixCount++;
}
```

Comment: Your variables are awfully named. More people can help you the more well named they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
     if ("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(crs) && "yes".equalsIgnoreCase(cty)) {
        mixCount++;
     }
```

However it would be simpler to use the database to do this.

```
 String query = "SELECT count(1) FROM table WHERE book = 'yes' && self = 'yes'";
```

This will return the count you need.